# why is my mail form not working?

Tags: php

I'm trying to setup an email form to send feedback from my website, here is the form:

```
 <form method='post' action='mailform.php'>
     <fieldset>
         <label for='message'><b>Reflection:<b></label><br/><br/>
         <p>Tell us what you thought of the Workshop, did you enjoy the tasks?, Could we have done anything different?</p>
         <textarea name='message' rows='15' cols='80'>
         </textarea><br/>
         <input type='submit' VALUE='Send' size='5' />
     </fieldset>
 </form>
```

and here is the `mailform.php`

```
  <?php
      $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
      mail("address here", $message);
  ?>
```

I keep getting an error which relates to the ?> bit at the end.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why didn't you include the error message you get?

Comment: sorry thought I did, my bad: Warning: mail() expects at least 3 parameters, 2 given in mailform.php on line 3

Comment: Now you can see the mail() function expects 3 parameters and you are giving it 2. http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mail.php

Comment: It expects 3 parameters because the authors (rightfully) thought that it's logical to divide parameters in 3 required ones. Next time you get such error, go to php.net, check the function in question and follow the rules found in the manual.

Comment: Because that's how the method was written by the PHP developers????

Comment: how does this question not show any research effort?? how would I have written the code for the code not to work in the first place?? ridiculous!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [mail()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mail.php) function expects 3 parameters:

```
$targetEmail = 'whoever@email.com';
$subject = 'Sending e-mails from PHP is fun!';
$message = 'Do you agree?';

mail($targetEmail, $subject, $message);
```

Comment: I needed to add a subject line, after this it worked fine

Answer (score 2):

[mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) has three overloads. to, subject, message.

Try:

```
<?php
  $message = $_REQUEST['message'];
  mail("address here", "subject line", $message);
?>
```

I have to advise for email that you use a pre-fab'd script or library. It's safer, cleaner, and you won't have to worry about headers or anything.

Comment: do I have to declare "subject line"?

Comment: You have to read the official docs! The first parameter is the e-mail you want to send the message to; the second is the subject of the e-mail; the third, the message itself.